# Convert mm/dd/yy hr:min:sec to yyyy-mm-dd hr:min:sec

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I want to convert (this is as in Syabase SQL)

**'09/29/2012  08:23:00' to '2012-09-29 08:23:00'**

This what i have tried but failed

```
select convert(varchar,convert(datetime, '09/29/2012 08:23:00', 101),123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 120 instead of 123.

```
 select convert(varchar(20),convert(datetime, '09/29/2012 08:23:00', 101),120)
```

See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm

Comment: didn't worked out :( its says cannot convert 09/29/2012 08:23:00 to timestamp,SQL CODE=-157

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you are getting that date format from but if it is from a table in the database what you can do is use the following to convert the date directly from the table.

Lets assume the date is in a table called MyTable and the date column is called MyDate

```
SELECT dateformat(MyDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
FROM MyTable;
```

You can test this out with the current datetime using the following:

```
SELECT dateformat(getdate(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
```